# MomentJS - Add month to date to specific day of week

Tags: javascript

Was trying to get only Saturdays of months ahead

using:

```
var momentDt = moment('2017-03-18').add(1); 
//or 2 or 3
```

But add 1 gives 2017-04-18 which is Tuesday.

Short of getting a day of the week and subtracting it from the original is there a setting in moment I can use to simply accomplish this?

Comment: See the [Day of Week](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) part of the documentation.

Comment: Ok got it thanks. You want the points please answer.

Comment: I have answered with more detail

Comment: FIY, you should use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/docs/), moment is a bit old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short of getting a day of the week and subtracting it from the original is there a setting in moment I can use to simply accomplish this?**

Yes see the [Day of Week](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) part of the documentation.

You can use the `day()` method of moment passing in the required day as either a string e.g. `moment.day(Saturday)` would give you the date of next Saturday. You can also pass in the number of the day e.g. `moment.day(20)` for 2 Saturdays from now (6 + 7 + 7).